# How Hadoop run OpenGL program with JNI

Tags: opengl, hadoop, java-native-interface

I meet problems when I run a hadoop program with JNI, could you help me? Thank you.

I try to run a Java program which utilize jni to call an OpenGL program in Hadoop 2.4.0.

This is my MapReduce program

1.FakeSegmentForJni.java

```
public class FakeSegmentForJni 
{  
    public static native boolean Init (String file);
    public static native boolean write ();  
    public static native String SegmentALine (String line);  
    public static native  int runproject ();
    static   
    {  
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6");
        System.load("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1");
        System.load("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6");
        System.load("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1");
        System.load("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2");
        System.load("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0");
        System.load("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2");
        System.load("/lib/ld-linux.so.2");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6");

        System.load("/home/grid/MR/facksegement/easyopengl/libFakeSegmentForJni.so");    
    }  
}
```

2.TestFakeSegmentForJni.java

```
import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;

import org.apache.hadoop.filecache.DistributedCache;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;

import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.URI;
public class TestFakeSegmentForJni {
public static class MapTestJni extends Mapper<Writable, Text, Text, Text> {  

    protected String s;  
    protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException  
    {  
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6");
        System.load("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1");
        System.load("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6");
        System.load("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1");
        System.load("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2");
        System.load("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0");
        System.load("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2");
        System.load("/lib/ld-linux.so.2");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6");
        System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6");

        System.load("/home/grid/MR/facksegement/easyopengl/libFakeSegmentForJni.so");  



        FakeSegmentForJni.runproject();
        FakeSegmentForJni.Init("Lex.txt");  
        s = FakeSegmentForJni.SegmentALine("jni-value");  
    }  

    protected void map(Writable key, Text value, Context context)  
    throws IOException, InterruptedException {  

        // the format of input value is:  
        //    mcid totaltimes item1 item2(itemkey=itemvalue)  

        context.write(new Text("key"), new Text(s.toString()));  
    }  
}     
public static class ReduceTestJni extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {  
protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)  
    throws IOException, InterruptedException {  

        String outString = "";  
        for (Text value: values)  
        {  
            outString = value.toString();  
        }  
        //FakeSegmentForJni.runproject();  
        context.write(key, new Text(outString));  
    }  
}  
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void runTestJni (String[] args) throws Exception {  

    //  the configuration  
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();  
    GenericOptionsParser goparser = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args);  
    String otherargs [] = goparser.getRemainingArgs();  


    // adding the current dir to java library path.
    conf.set("mapred.child.java.opts", "-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu:/lib/i386-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa:/home/grid/hadoop/lib/native:/home/grid/jdk1.7.0_21/jre/lib/i386:/home/grid/jdk1.7.0_21/jre/lib/i386/client:/home/grid/jdk1.7.0_21/jre/lib/i386/server:./"); 
    //DistributedCache.addCacheArchive(new URI("hdfs://192.168.1.231:9000/lib/lib.jar#./"),conf);
    // the job  
    Job job;  
    job = new Job(conf, "@here-TestFakeSegmentForJni-hadoopJni");  
    job.setJarByClass(TestFakeSegmentForJni.class);  

    // the mapper  
    job.setMapperClass(MapTestJni.class);  
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);  
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);  

    // the reducer  
    job.setReducerClass(ReduceTestJni.class);  
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);  
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);  
    job.setNumReduceTasks(1);  

    // the path  
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherargs[0]));  
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherargs[1]));  

    job.waitForCompletion(true);  
}  
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {  

    System.out.println ("In this project, we test jni!\n");  
    System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3");
    System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1");
    System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1");
    System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6");
    System.load("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1");
    System.load("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6");
    System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6");
    System.load("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6");
    System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6");
    System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1");
    System.load("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1");
    System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0");
    System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6");
    System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1");
    System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3");
    System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1");
    System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0");
    System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0");
    System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0");
    System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0");
    System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1");
    System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1");
    System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1");
    System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2");
    System.load("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0");
    System.load("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2");
    System.load("/lib/ld-linux.so.2");
    System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6");
    System.load("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6");

    System.load("/home/grid/MR/facksegement/easyopengl/libFakeSegmentForJni.so");   
    // test jni on linux local  
    /*String s = FakeSegmentForJni.SegmentALine("now we test FakeSegmentForJni"); 
    System.out.print(s);*/  
      System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
    // test jni on hadoop  
    new TestFakeSegmentForJni().runTestJni(args);  

} // main  

}
```

This is my C++ OpenGL code

FakeSegmentForJni.cpp

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>  
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h> 
#include "FakeSegmentForJni.h"  
using namespace std;

vector <string> WordVec;   
string sWordt;
vector <string> WordVect; 
void init();
void display();
int runpro();
bool write(string,const char*);

void init()
{
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glOrtho(-5, 5, -5, 5, 5, 15);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
gluLookAt(0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
}

void display()
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glColor3f(1.0, 0, 0);
glutWireTeapot(3);
glFlush();
}

bool write(string ss,const char *ff)
{
string hh=" open f1 fail";
string vv=" write f3 fail"; 
ofstream outfile(ff);
if(!outfile)
    {
        WordVect.push_back(vv);
        printf("write f3 fail");
        return false;
    }
else
    {
        outfile<<ss<<endl;
    }
outfile.close();
return true;
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_FakeSegmentForJni_runproject(JNIEnv *env, jclass obj)
{
write("runpro()","/home/grid/f3/runpro().dat");
int c=2;
int angleX=0;
char* v[]={"hello","world"};
glutInit(&c, v);
write(" glutInit;","/home/grid/f3/glutInit.dat");
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_SINGLE);
write(" glutInit;","/home/grid/f3/glutInitDisplayMode.dat");
glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
write(" glutInit;","/home/grid/f3/glutInitWindowPosition.dat");
glutInitWindowSize(300, 300);
write(" glutInit;","/home/grid/f3/glutInitWindowSize.dat");
glutCreateWindow("OpenGL 3D View");
write(" glutInit;","/home/grid/f3/glutCreateWindow.dat");
init(); 
glutDisplayFunc(display);
write(" glutInit;","/home/grid/f3/glutDisplayFunc.dat");
    while(true)
    {
    glutMainLoopEvent();
    write(" glutInit;","/home/grid/f3/glutMainLoopEvent.dat");
    angleX=angleX+1;
    glutPostRedisplay();
    write(" glutInit;","/home/grid/f3/glutPostRedisplay.dat");
    }
return 0;
}

JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_FakeSegmentForJni_Init(JNIEnv *env, jclass obj, jstring line)  
{  
    write(" open f3 success","/home/grid/f3/fs.dat");  
    const char *pFileName = NULL;  
    pFileName = env->GetStringUTFChars (line, false);  
    if (pFileName == NULL)  
    return false;  
    ifstream in (pFileName);
    if (!in)  
    {  
        cerr << "Can not open the file of " << pFileName << endl;  
        return false;  
    }  
    string sWord;  
    while (getline (in, sWord))  
    {  
        WordVec.push_back(sWord);
    } 
return true;  
}  

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_FakeSegmentForJni_SegmentALine(JNIEnv *env, jclass obj, jstring line)  
{  
    char buf[128];  
    buf[0] = 0;  
    const char *str = NULL;  
    str = env->GetStringUTFChars(line, false);  
    if (str == NULL)  
        return NULL;  
    strcpy (buf, str);  
    if (!WordVec.empty())  
        strcat (buf, WordVec.at(0).c_str());
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(line, str);  
    return env->NewStringUTF(buf);  
 }
```

I compile the OpenGL program in to a share library(libFakeSegmentForJni.so), and I package the hadoop program in to TestFakeSegmentForJniHadoop.jar. libFakeSegmentForJni.so depends on other shared libraries. I upload these shared libraries in to HDFS. I run the hadoop problem with the following command.

```
bin/hadoop jar /home/grid/MR/facksegement/easyopengl/TestFakeSegmentForJniHadoop.jar \
-files /home/grid/MR/facksegement/easyopengl/libFakeSegmentForJni.so,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/input/Lex.txt,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libjvm.so,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/ld-2.19.so,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libglut.so.3.9.0,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libxcb-present.so.0.0.0,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/ld-linux.so.2,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libm-2.19.so,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libxcb.so.1,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/lib,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libm.so.6,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libxcb.so.1.1.0,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libc-2.19.so,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libpthread-2.19.so,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libxcb-sync.so.1,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libc.so.6,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libpthread.so.0,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libxcb-sync.so.1.0.0,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libdl-2.19.so,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libstdc++.so.6,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libXdamage.so.1,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libdl.so.2,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.19,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libXdamage.so.1.1.0,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libdrm.so.2,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libX11.so.6,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libXdmcp.so.6,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libdrm.so.2.4.0,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libX11.so.6.3.0,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libexpat.so.1,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libX11-xcb.so.1,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libXext.so.6,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libexpat.so.1.6.0,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libXext.so.6.4.0,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libXau.so.6,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libXfixes.so.3,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libgcc_s.so.1,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libXau.so.6.0.0,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libXfixes.so.3.1.0,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libglapi.so.0,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libxcb-dri2.so.0,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libXi.so.6,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libglapi.so.0.0.0,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libxcb-dri2.so.0.0.0,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libXi.so.6.1.0,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libGL.so.1,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libxcb-dri3.so.0,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libxshmfence.so.1,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libGL.so.1.2.0,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libxcb-dri3.so.0.0.0,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libxshmfence.so.1.0.0,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libGLU.so.1,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libxcb-glx.so.0,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libXxf86vm.so.1,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libGLU.so.1.3.1,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libxcb-glx.so.0.0.0,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libXxf86vm.so.1.0.0,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libglut.so.3,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/lib/libxcb-present.so.0,\
hdfs://slave1:9000/input/f1.dat \
/input \
/output/outputJNI
```

But I got the following error:

```
15/05/25 10:06:55 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1432519520706_0002_m_000004_2, Status : FAILED
Exception from container-launch: 
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: 
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:464)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:379)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:589)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:195)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:283)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:79)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I guess the error is caused on JNI. I write a small test Java code to call liboglgpu.so via JNI, it works fine. I also ldd liboglgpu.so, every libraries are linked

My OpenGL program includes standard C++ code and OpenGL code. The standard C++ code can work fine, but when hadoop run the OpenGL code, the program cannot work.

If I run the hadoop program with Eclipse(standalone mode), the program can run on the native. While, if I run the hadoop program in distributed mode, the program cannot run on the datanode. The namenode and datanode both have opengl environment.

I've tried many different things：

1)  liboglgpu.so depends on other shared libraries. I've tried to send these libraries to the hadoop distributed file system, and run hadoop program with “-files” to distribute these libraries.

2)  I try to load these libraries from the code level (using e.g. system .load("usr/lib/libGL.so.0.1");).

3)  I set JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH in hadoop-env.sh、yarn-env.sh;I set LD_LIBRARY_PATH in /etc/profile. The path is where these libraries locate.

4)  I put these libraries in to the path XXX/hadoop/lib/native

Will you tell me what else should I do? Why the hadoop program cannot run?

Comment: sorry, liboglgpu.so and libFakeSegmentForJni.so is the same thing, i write  libFakeSegmentForJni.so  into  liboglgpu.so by mistake

Comment: i also used the distribute cache. but it did not work